# Is it possible to read records from a MySQL or Oracle Server which were created after a specific Timestamp, even if there is no Timestamp column?

Tags: mysql, oracle, rdbms

I have to read from a remote MySQL server periodically.Say if the table does not have a timestamp column,is there a way to keep track of the rows which i already read.I only need to read the rows which were created after my last access.

Comment: can you just log an id in that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, if the tables are in Oracle, would be to enable flashback queries and then you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   your_table AS OF TIMESTAMP SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE x
  WHERE  t.primary_key_column = x.primary_key_column
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle we can use the SCN to figure this out, through the `ora_rowscn` pseudo-column. This allows us to determine when the row was updated. There is also a neat `scn_to_timestamp()` function.

```
Select scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn),
   t.*
from your_table t
where t.id = 23;
```

This is only the approximate time, because by default Oracle tracks the SCN at the block level. If the table has row-level dependency enabled you can get the SCN at the lower level of granularity. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns007.htm)